# Rails does not work when terminal exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I run a rails app.

```
rails s -p 5000 -e production &
```

The website works fine.

But, when terminal (which runs above command) exits, the website only shows blank page.

When I open terminal again, the rails process is still running.

I check nginx log. After terminal exits, nginx seems stop talking rails. Nginx just returns HTTP 200.

Below is nginx config.

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mydomain.org;
    rails_env       production;
    root            /home/user/website/public;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    access_log      /opt/nginx/logs/website.log;
    error_log       /opt/nginx/logs/website_err.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missing `-d` or `--daemon` option for run server as a daemon:

```
rails s -p 5000 -e production -d &
```